# Is that possible to retrieve a content source for platform or quick actions?

Tags: apex, quickaction, global-actions

Assuming I have custom `Test_Object__c`, two custom actions on it, one - Visualforce action with page definition like following

```
<apex:page standardController="Test_Object__c">
    <h1>This is some VF Action Template</h1>
</apex:page>
```

and another custom Lightning action

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride">
    <h1>This is some LEX Action Template</h1>
</aura:component>
```

How can I retrieve those two action and retrieve that source for the first one is `TestPage` and that source for the second one is `TestComp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all action related to some entity it is possible to use [QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_quickaction.htm#apex_class_system_quickaction)

like following

```
Object v  =  
    JSON.serialize( QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Test_Object__c'));  
 System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + v );
```

This method would return the list of [DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult instances](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_quickaction_describeavailablequickactionresult.htm#apex_class_quickaction_describeavailablequickactionresult) with four fields:

1. actionEnumOrId which appears to be id of [Tooling API QuickActionDefinition object record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_quickactiondefinition.htm)
2. label
3. name
4. type

[image]

To get more information we need to call [another method called QuickAction.DescribeQuickActions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_quickaction.htm#apex_class_system_quickaction)

```
List<QuickAction.DescribeQuickActionResult> result = 
    QuickAction.DescribeQuickActions(new List<String> {
        'Test_Object__c.VF', 'Test_Object__c.LEX'});
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ result2: ' + JSON.serialize( result ) );
```

[image]

This method returns list of [DescribeQuickActionResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_quickaction_describequickactionresult.htm#apex_class_quickaction_describequickactionresult) which have more information about content source, for example, it is possible to get `visualforcepagename` and `visualforcepageurl` for Visualforce action and `lightningcomponentbundlename` and `lightningcomponentqualifiedname` for Lightning actions.